# ESP32-WROVER-E CE certification is needed on a new PCB?

Tags: esp32, ce

We are making a new PCB that integrates a ESP32-WROVER-E chip. Indeed, ESP32 is welded to a new pcb.

As ESP32 module is already CE certified and we are not modifying anything of this module, do we need to make a new RED Certification of the new PCB ?

Best regards,
Estibaly

Comment: Can traces in the PCB become a source of EM radiation, or can the PCB be affected by nearby EM radiation? Can the box? Can the power supply or its cable? The fact that one component is compliant does not mean the whole system is. Of course, it’s much easier when you start from components which are compliant, but it’s easy to start from a compliant component and end up with a non-compliant one.

Comment: It would help telling everybody what a ESP32-WROVER-E module is and what it does ?

Comment: [Welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welding) and [soldering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldering) are very different things in English.  Did you mean soldered rather than welded?

Answer (score 1):

In general:
**Selling products that are not compliant or that do not have a CE-marking is illegal in the EU**, but there are exceptions for certain kinds of product.

In case your product requires a CE-marking (which is the case for any electronic device), you as the manufacturer/importer/seller have to declare that your product complies with all directives that are relevant for your product (for electronic devices that is mainly the EMC directive, but there are others like e.g. RoHS). You do not strictly need to have an external laboratory verify the compliance. If you make the neccessary tests yourself and if you are sure that your product complies with the relevant standards, you can put the CE-marking on your product. That's entirely your own responsibility, the marking just says "I, the manufacturer, declare that ... complies with ...".

Though, for legal reasons it is recommended to have an external and independent laboratory verify compliance.

The CE-marking is bound to the product as a whole. If you are manufacturing a component of a larger device, only the larger device must have the marking. No one would be able to see the marking of a sub-component that is embedded inside of a housing and the marking must be visible, non-removable, etc..
Typically, all subcomponents need to be compliant as well, but compliance has to be verified for the whole product.

Comment: Wikipedia notwithstanding 'self certification' is still certification, and the CE marking is certification. And in many cases, the certification requires (by law), an assessment of conformity by a certified test agency.

Comment: @david thanks for your comment, I corrected my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As the previous reply suggests the self certification would be the easiest but not the least expensive as this requires that you have the necessary (and calibrated) equipment to do the measurements. When I say "easiest" I mean that you know what you are doing !
If I am not mistaken, the ESP32-WROVER-E is some type of Wifi / BT module and so EN 300 328 v2.2.2 is applicable since 2019. So for starters you need to make sure the documentation provided for the module says it is compliant to the latest version of En 300 328, otherwise it is null !
Integrating a module like the ESP32-WROVER-E or any other Wifi / BT module onto / into another product (such as another PCB with power supply and a case as a minimum) will still require some confirmation that the overall product does NOT degrade certain parameters of the Wifi module. If I recall correctly this is on the "blocking receiver" capability of the module, which was NOT previously an issue prior to 2020 more or less. Now it IS ! and you need to ensure the "receiver blocking"capacity of the module is not degraded by the introduction of the module into your product. This is NOT a simple measurement to make as it requires both the correct, calibrated measurement apparatus, but also requires you to set the Wifi module in certain test modes etc. that you will need to discover from the manufacturer. You may find it much cheaper to go through a Notified Body to verify this for you than to complicate your life and do the self certification yourself etc (unless that is, you know what you're doing !)